# Create lines in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to create some lines in MS Word 2010 to write some comments. I would like when someone prints the documents to write on the lines. However, if someones wants to fill in the comment electronically the line to be decreased/deleted as he/she types the comments. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if what you want, but : http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-HA010030746.aspx

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who have tried themselves to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things; 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried.

Comment: I know you requested Word but I would suggest looking into Acrobat.  Acrobat has a form option that can be submitted electronically and print options that are best suited for what you are trying to do.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-61kV5awl8

Comment: @Gjordis,I'd like to apologize but I didn’t know how Superuser works. Trying to find a solution, I found this forum and I made my question.

Comment: My problem: In a Word document I want to create a space where someone can write comments. What I have done up to now is to create from the Developer a Rich Text Content Control and I have inserted some lines in case someone wants to printout the form. I would like though if someone wants to write something electronically, the line to be deleted automatically (and not by the user, if possible) and not to move along with the text. You may see the control below:
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_____________________________________________________________________

Comment: I apologize once more because both I am not an expert in Word and English is not my native language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can get the effect that you want by setting a single tab stop at the right margin, using line style, and then type a <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add a line where people can type in some words like a fillable form or print out the doc and fill it in by hand.

To do this, you have two options depending on how your end result will be:

**Option 1** - Use a once Cell Table with only the bottom border visible.

**Option 2** - Insert a Line and Wrap the text to either Behind or in Front of Text.

Though if you want to do forms right, you would turn it into a PDF with fillable forms, but that requires paid software that you probably don't have.